# RestAssured - Provide the contenttype of body as raw text without quotes

Tags: java, curl, rest-assured

I need to pass raw text as body without quotes in my rest assured

Sample code used:

```
String command = "dumpsys package com.android.chrome | grep versionName"
request.pathParam("deviceId", deviceId);
request.contentType(ContentType.TEXT).body(command);
```

but still it reads it as String with quotes but  here I need to pass the body as below

`dumpsys package com.android.chrome | grep versionName`

But it is getting passed as

`"dumpsys package com.android.chrome | grep versionName"`

due to which I am getting failure in my case

Comment: How do you know it sent with quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body is sent without quotes. You can try with `netcat` tool.

Start listening on some port (e.g. `9123`): `netcat -l -p 9123`

Then run the code:

```java
String command = "dumpsys package com.android.chrome | grep versionName";
RestAssured
  .given()
    .baseUri("http://localhost:9123")
    .basePath("/{deviceId}")
    .pathParam("deviceId", 123)
    .contentType(ContentType.TEXT)
    .body(command)
  .get();
```

And watch the log of `netcat`:

```
alexey@master-host:~$ netcat -l -p 9123
GET /123 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 53
Host: 0.0.0.0:9123
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.20.1)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

dumpsys package com.android.chrome | grep versionName
```